# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input - undefined auth token

Tags: javascript, fetch, token, jwt

I'm trying to make a fetch request to my back-end route, but it seems cookie-parser isn't actually parsing the data? The authorization header is getting through successfully as well. Here's my fetch request:

```
    async componentDidMount() {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/tweets`, {
          headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${this.context.userToken}`,
          }
      })
      const tweets = await res.json();
      console.log(tweets)
}
```

It's hitting the route just fine, and if I disable my auth middleware I do get the data, but when I try to console.log my token, it's just undefined. req.cookies is just a null object. Here's my auth middleware:

```
const restoreUser = (req, res, next) => {
  // token being parsed from request's cookies by the cookie-parser middleware
  // function in app.js:
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  console.log("TOKEN:", token)

  if (!token) {
    // Send a "401 Unauthorized" response status code
    return res.status(401).end();
  }

  return jwt.verify(token, secret, null, async (err, jwtPayload) => {
    if (err) {
      err.status = 401;
      return next(err);
    }

    const { id } = jwtPayload.data;

    try {
      req.user = await User.findByPk(id);
    } catch (e) {
      // remove the token cookie
      res.clearCookie("token");
      return next(e);
    }

    if (!req.user) {
      // Send a "401 Unauthorized" response status code
      // along with removing the token cookie
      res.clearCookie("token");
      return res.status(401).end();
    }

    return next();
  });
};
```

EDIT: I got it to work by changing

```
const { token } = req.cookies;
```

to:

```
const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
```

I'm still unclear as to why the former didn't work

Comment: what you have in `req.headers`?

Comment: authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7ImlkIjoxMiwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0QHRlc3QuY29tIn0sImlhdCI6MTYwNTQ3MjIyNiwiZXhwIjoxNjA2MDc3MDI2fQ.e21sPaOUT2Lix6SM5XyXONqgO_MAruX2mET_uUtfD_Y',

Comment: possibly something wrong in `cookie-parser middleware`

Comment: that's what I'm thinking. I got it to work by changing ```const { token } = req.cookies;``` to ```const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')```